# Compatibility pb with bootsrap and modals in header of my website

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pb with boostrap modal. I added a simple bootstrap homepage to my website. Only addition to this homepage, the header that i use throughout my website, in which there is a signup button that, when clicked, opens a modal. Impossible to make it work on the homepage ! Other js also dont work on the homempage, I guess due to conflict with JS and bootstrap. Can you help me ?

```
        <div class="btn-register">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <span>
                Sign up
            </span>
        </div>
```

This doeas not work on http://youmindit.net/
but if you click on "RECENT", close to the youmindit logo, then the modal appears fine, because you are not on a page with bootstrap anymore.

I hope you dont need more info !

Thx for your help

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Your homepage doesn't contain your registration container so there is nothing for the modal button to produce.

```
          Rejoignez Youmindit aujourd'hui !

      </h2>

        <div class="social">
          <a href="/fb_signup/">
            <div class="social-col sfacebook">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span class="media">Facebook</span>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="/twt_signup/">
            <div class="social-col stwitter">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><span class="media">Twitter</span>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="/google_signup/">
            <div class="social-col sgoogle">
              <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i><span class="media">Google+</span>
            </div>
          </a>

        </div>
        <p>Inscrivez-vous avec votre adresse email</p>
        <form data-parsley-validate id="signup" action="javascript:showRegisterModal();" method="post">
          <div>
            <input class="field email" type="text" name="email" required data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-remote="/check_email/" data-parsley-remote-reverse="true" data-parsley-remote-message="Cette adresse email est déjà utilisée !" data-parsley-required-message="Vous devez choisir une adresse mail !"
            data-parsley-type-message="L'adresse mail doit être valide!" data-parsley-errors-container=".errors-list" placeholder="Entrez votre adresse email">
     <input type="submit" value="S'inscrire" class="btn-signup valid_email"></input>
  </form>
 </div>
<div class="errors-list"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Actualy you're right it is a call for another html template. And it does so for every other pages. Does it need to be different, ie included in the page for boostrap homepage ?

Comment: I imagine the code for that modal needs to be added to your home page and probably other css/js assets hooked into it. But I can't say for sure.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time vanburenx, this might be what i'll have to do afterwards, at least the most simple solution !

Comment: You're very welcome! If this answered you're question please mark it as answered so others can benefit from it.